# Telegram Bot - remove/ignore link from message

Tags: regex, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm facing the issue that my bot answers question it isn't supposed to. My regex for finding questions is r".{2,}?+". I don't want to force a white space after the question mark. Now it detects questions in messages with a link, often it contains a question mark.
My idea was to search for links with r'http\S+' and remove this with re.sub. The problem is, that I can't find a way to edit the message from the MessageHandler before the entry_point. Any advice?

```
class EveryOtherQuestion(ConversationHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            entry_points=[MessageHandler(Filters.regex(re.compile(r".{2,}\?+", re.IGNORECASE)),
                                         EveryOtherQuestion.everyOtherQuestion),
                          ],
            states={},
            fallbacks=[]
        )

    @staticmethod
    def everyOtherQuestion(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        answers = [
            "idT",
            "Gwiss ned!",
            "Auf keinen Fall",
            "Da kannst drauf wetten",
            "Natürlich nicht! So ein Bach!",
            "Ja",
            "Nein",
            "Wie kommst du denn da drauf?! Spinnst gwiss a weng?!",
        ]
        update.message.reply_text(text=random.choice(answers), quote=True)
```

Comment: Yes, make it match the entire string, `r"^.{2,}\?+$"`

Comment: The question was posted also on [PTBs issue tracker](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/2752). @Jona please update this question with the info given there and vice versa.